# Regex: match second pattern if preceding pattern is matched

Tags: regex

I'm looking for regex to match date type patterns which start with hyphen and possible `* + digit` that might come after it. I have text input like this:

```
- 19/03/2081
- 20 / 02 / 1982
- 11/3/1950 * 1
- 21 / 11 / 2120 * 500000
01 / 09 / 2021
- 21 / 09 / 2021
20 / 09 / 2021 * 3
***12
```

My current regex is this: `\-(\s*\d+\s*\/\s*\d+\s*\/\s*\d+)|\s*\*\s*\d+`. This correctly matches the following:

```
- 19/03/2081
- 20 / 02 / 1982
- 11/3/1950 * 1
- 21 / 11 / 2120 * 500000
- 21 / 09 / 2021
```

However, it also matches `* 3` and `*12` which it shouldn't. Basically I'm looking for regex which would match `* + digit` only if defined preceding pattern would match. Is this possible using regex?

Comment: Instead of using  OR condition `|`, you can make the second part optional with this format: `(prerequisite)(optional)?`. Here's what you might want: [`\-(\s*\d+\s*\/\s*\d+\s*\/\s*\d+)(\s*\*\s*\d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/FoudhG/latest)

Comment: Yes, this works. Can you post this as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your regex with this:

```
\-(\s*\d+\s*\/\s*\d+\s*\/\s*\d+)(\s*\*\s*\d+)?
```

**Explanation:**

- Here you dont need `or(|)` in the end as you want to make sure that
  `* digits` should only be matched when it is preceded by your date
  format.
- `(\s*\*\s*\d+)?` made a capturing group where `?` marks ensures that it
  is optional.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pq4D2k/1)